# Finding probability of getting from State $1$ to State $3$ in Markov Chain

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

> Finding probability of getting from State $1$ to State $3$ in Markov Chain

I have this transition matrix $P=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2& 1/4&1/4\\1/2&1/4&1/4\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}$

With states $1,2,3$ in order as rows and columns.

I want to know the probability of reaching state $3$ from state $1$, $p_{13}$

However I see this problem where a path from $1$ to $3$ can be stuck in a loop from going from $1\to 2\to 1\to 2\to...$

There are finite paths $1\to 2\to 3$ which is $\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{16}$

But I have a few looping paths where either $1$ goes to $2$ and back to $1$, or the chain can just repeated at state $1$ or state $2$ for any amount of time before leaving.

How do you account for this?

Comment: You've misunderstood the question, I think.  There are no paths involved; they just want you to read the transition matrix.

Comment: @user3716267
 I believe you're right since Daniel S. seemed to cover whatever interpretation it could have meant.

Comment: The probability of going from State 1 to State 3 in a single step is $\frac14$.  The probability of going from State 1 to State 3 after an arbitrarily large number of steps converges to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of getting from state 1 to state 3 in 1 step is 1/4. The probability of getting from state 1 to state 3 in exactly $n$ steps is the (1,3) entry of $P^n$.  The probability of getting from state 1 to state 3 in infinite steps is 1.  Finally, the probability of getting from state 1 to state 3 in at most $n$ steps is the (1,3) entry in the sum of $P+P^2+P^3+...+P^n$